# A Not-So-Simple Connect Wall

Tags: connect-wall

I was making a connect wall, and I finished it late at night (2:00 am).
I was glad and it was one of my hardest yet. However, as I took a sip from my coffee cup, I fell asleep and (I assume) coffee splashed onto my puzzle.

I woke up at around 10:30, and noticed that coffee had covered the bottom right phrase in my puzzle, and realised that I couldnt remember the phrase there!

So, I would've corrected it, and figured I just needed to solve my puzzle for myself. But I'm lazy. So solve my puzzle.

> ```
>   Hanger Lane     Wimbledon     Elizabeth      Tabby
>
>     Spain       French Open     Victoria       Ringo
>
>     Jane          Taiwan        Joanna        Chateau
>
>    Temple         George         John      *coffee spill*
> ```

a) Propose a word or phrase to fill the gap currently occupied by the coffee spill.

b) Sort the 16 words into 4 groups of 4.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not finished yet but I put some together.

> **King/Queen:** George, Victoria, Elizabeth, John(?)
>  **Tennis tournament:** Wimbledon, French Open
>  **Building:** Temple, Chateau, Hanger Lane(?)
>  **Music:** Jane, Ringo

What I also found out is that

> many things probably has to do something with the UK or French.

I hope it will help someone or I'm totally wrong

Comment: @Stiv it might be worth encoding your comment in rot13

Comment: Re-posting my comment from this morning in rot13 (couldn't suss it on my phone this morning!)... Thanks @poisInANutshell. Some pointers: rot13(Gurer ner npghnyyl 5 HX zbanepuf ba gur obneq (Wnar pbhyq or Ynql Wnar Terl, jub ervtarq sbe bayl n jrrx). Unatre Ynar vf n Ghor fgbc va Ybaqba (whfg yvxr Ivpgbevn, Jvzoyrqba naq Grzcyr), naq lbh jba'g trg sne jvgu gur graavf orpnhfr gubfr ner gur bayl 2 ba gur obneq! Gurer'f tbvat gb or N YBG bs qrpbl tebhcf (r.t. 3 bs gur Orngyrf ner yvfgrq - V fhfcrpg gur zvffvat fdhner jvyy ABG or Cnhy...). Rkcrpg fbzr jbeqcynl!)

Comment: You are on the right track with one of your groups, but you have found a couple of my decoys along the way.